# Strange autoincrement issue with Navicat data transfer for MySQL to SqLite and JPA/Hibernate in Java

Tags: mysql, sqlite, jpa, auto-increment, navicat

I converted a MySQL database to SQLite using Navicat Premium 11.2 Data Transfer Wizard. Now I would like to persist a newly created Job entity to the SqLite Database using JPA in Java. While saving a new Job entity works fine with MySQL it fails with SQlite:

> SQL Error: 19, SQLState: null
>
> [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT]  Abort due to constraint violation (NOT NULL constraint failed: job.id)

The AUTOINCREMENT option of the id column in the SqLite table is false while it is true for MySQL. I would expect the auto increment to work in SqLite even if AUTOINCREMENT is false since I have an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column in SQlite and the meaning of AUTOINCREMENT in SQlite is slightly different from the meaning in MySQL: http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q1

**If I make a minor change to the table structure with Navicat (e.g. length of description column) or if I set AUTOINCREMENT to true, save, set it back to false and save again, the persistance of new Jobs works just fine.**

=>The AUTOINCREMENT does not have to be true for JPA to be able to insert new entities with auto generated ids.

=>I guess that the SqLite file that is created by the Navicat Data Transfer Wizard is somehow corrupted and that saving the table structure again somehow repairs the issue.

**Is this a real Navicat bug or is there a JPA setting to make the persistance of new entities more robust?**

The definition of my JPA persistance unit is

```
</persistence-unit>
        <persistence-unit name="dBManager_SQLite" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.sqlite.JDBC" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLiteDialect" />
            <!-- use new generator mappings as noted here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#ann-setup-properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="true"/>
            <!-- Connection parameters are defined by the 'DbManager' according to the command line arguments -->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Here is a zipped sqLite database file that (only) contains the Job table:

http://gfk.bplaced.net/mediawiki/images/4/49/Test.zip

Comment: Hi, I am Kit working for Navciat. Please contact [us](https://help.navicat.com/hc/en-us/requests/new), see if there is anything that we can help

Comment: Hi Kit. Thank you for your reply. I already got some feedback here: https://community.navicat.com/forum/navicat-product/navicat-premium/4361-strange-autoincrement-issue-after-data-transfer-from-mysql-to-sqlite